# How do I merge multiple Map/JSON Object into One Map

Tags: apex, json, map

I am trying to build a json out of List of Maps but I need to merge few maps together when matching key is found.

How can I merge few Apex Map Object values ?

For example:

```
Map<String,Object> parent1 = new Map<String,Object>{
      'field1' =>  'value'
    };
Map<String,Object> root1 = new Map<String,Object>{
      'root' => parent1
};
Map<String,Object> parent2 = new Map<String,Object>{
      'field2' =>  'value'
    };
Map<String,Object> root2 = new Map<String,Object>{
      'root' => parent2
};
```

If Ill add each Map root1 and root2 to a List:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> listOfMap =new List<Map<String,Object>>();  
listOfMap.add(root1);
listOfMap.add(root2);
```

Results will look like this :

```
[{"root":{"field1":"value"}},{"root":{"field2":"value"}}]
```

Which is closer, But what I'm trying to do is to merge this results into one Object.

For example my end result should look like :

```
{
    "root": {
      "field1": "value",
      "field2": "value"
    }
  }
```

If ill place those 2 Maps using putAll() - Instead of appending the values I will always get the last.

```
{"root":{"field2":"value"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = new Map<String,Object>{'root'=> new Map<String,Object>{'field1'=>'value','field2'=>'value'}};
System.debug(JSON.serialize(jsonMap));
```

Your parent map key is root, so if you wanna add field3, you can

```
((Map<String,Object>)jsonMap.get('root')).put('field3','value');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be doing `putAll()` on the child object of the root that you want to keep. That method does not do a recursive merge.

Given your examples, you'd want to do

```
root1.get('root').putAll(root2.get('root'));
```

Then, `root1` would contain its own fields plus the fields from `root2`.

Since you've typed your objects as `Map<String, Object>`, you'd have to cast the return value of `get()`:

```
(Map<String, Object>)root1.get('root').putAll((Map<String, Object>)root2.get('root'));
```

Comment: yes it makes sense but this is not working - get the following Error => Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void putAll(Object) from the type Object

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you were using generically-typed objects.